# Show that: $ \int_{E}{g_\infty(t)d\mu(t)}\leq \lim_{n}{\int_{E}{g_n(t)d\mu(t)}} $

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of $\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}$, such that $\{\min\big(0,f_n(.)\big)\}$ (the negative parts of $f_n$) is uniformly integrable.

Let $\{g_n\}$ be a sequence defined by: for all $n\geq 1$, $g_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f_i}$. So  $\{\min\big(0,g_n(.)\big)\}$  is also   uniformly integrable.

We suppose that there exists $g_\infty\in\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}}^{1}$ such that:
$$
g_\infty(t)=\lim_n g_n(t)\qquad a.e.
$$

Show that:
$$
\int_{E}{g_\infty(t)d\mu(t)}\leq \lim_{n}{\int_{E}{g_n(t)d\mu(t)}}
$$

An idea please.

Answer (score 0):

For a function $f$ write $f^+ = \max\{0,f(x)\}$ and $f^- = \min\{0,f(x)\}$ so that $f(x) = f^+(x) - f^-(x)$.

You have a sequence of functions $\{g_n\}$ with the property that $g_n \to g$ almost everywhere, and $\{g_n^-\}$ is uniformly integrable.

Note that $g_n^- \to g^-$ and $g_n^+ \to g^+$ almost everywhere. Since the measure space is finite you may employ uniform integrability and Vitali's theorem to conclude that
$$ \int_E g_n^- \, d\mu \to \int_E g^- \, d\mu $$
On the other hand, Fatou's lemma gives you
$$ \int_E g^+ \, d\mu \le \liminf_n \int_E g_n^+ \, d\mu.$$
Now combine these.